# Is a 9.6µs over-voltage transient long enough to fry my circuit (Details inside)?

Tags: automotive, tvs, circuit-protection, transient-suppression

I am designing a board for a 12V automotive environment, with a variety of input voltage transients including load dump and permanent 24V over-voltage. I am using a TVS at the input to clamp to around 60V followed by a TI LM5060, a power supply supervisor, which in case of an over-voltage above 18V (or overcurrent) will cut off the power to my circuit using an external 60V MOSFET. The LM5060 datasheet specifies a 9.6 microsecond delay from the onset of a over-voltage condition to the MOSFET gate turning off. On the other side of the LM5060 I have my bulk capacitor and number of linear regulators and other ICs which at their input can tolerate up to around 30V (or 45V depending on what parts I choose).

So my question is, during that 9.6µs it takes for LM5060 to kick in, how can I ensure that nothing on its down-side gets fried? Is a sufficiently large bulk capacitor (220uF?) enough to absorb that transient? Or would I be better off using a small zener? How would I choose a value for this zener/capacitor?

If anyone knows of a better/cheaper alternative to LM5060, please let me know. I only need it to provide over-voltage protection up to around 60V.

Comment: You can delay the input current arrival to LM5060 using a proper coil.

Comment: How much current does your circuit draw?  There are several inexpensive techniques but they vary according to how much current they have to pass.

Comment: my circuit draw a maximum of 1.4A.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there:
Typical FET response is measured in nanoseconds.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSDmfO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

```
Vshutdown > VzZD1 + VgthFET1

If VzZD1 = 50V and VgthFET1 = 3V then Vshutdown > 53V
```

As shown, FET1 may (will try to) destroy itself to protect the load.
Determine resistor sizes as follows:

```
R1 protects FET1  
(R2 > R1) ensures lower-impedance path through FET than load
```

Size R2 according to Ohm's law with Vout "grounded":

```
E = I * R
Edrop = Vin - Vout = 12V - 0V = 12V
R = Edrop / I
R = 12V / 1.4A = 8.57ohm
```

If Vzd1 = 12V and VgthFET1 = 3V, then Vshutoff = 15V:

```
Ir2 = E / R
Ir2 = 15V / 8.57ohm = 1.75A
```

FET1 will pass Vin - Vzd1 - VgthFET1 when active.
If R1 = 0 and Vin = 50V:

```
VdsFET1 = 50V - 12V - 3V = 35V
I = E / R
I = 35V / 25mOhm = 1400A //Zap!
```

If R1 = 4 ohm ("less" than R2) and Vin = 50V:

```
VdsFET1 = 50V - 12V - 3V = 35V
I = E / R
I = 35V / (4 + 25mOhm) = 8.70A
EdropR1 = 8.70A * 4Ohm = 34.8V
EdropFET = 8.70A * 0.025Ohm = 0.2V
P = I * E
PFET = 8.70A * 0.2V = 1.74W
PR1 = 8.70A * 34.8V = 302.76W //Warm
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. My circuit draws 1.4A. That means the voltage drop across the 200ohm resistor in your circuit will be be 1.4*200=280V!!! and R1 and that MOSFET would also have to a huge.

Comment: "Resistors need proper sizing" :P  I added additional sizing information.

Comment: Also, if Vin = 12V, with a 200ohm resistor and a 200ohm load, each resistor would drop 6V @ 15mA. Since 200 is waaay to big, your load would be unable to "demand" 1.4A from it. 1.4A is the maximum you intend to **request** from the power supply.

Comment: Do Zener diodes not need to have a current flowing through them to actually drop a voltage? Without a pull down resistor between the Zener and ground I'm not sure how this would work? Maybe my understanding is wrong?

Comment: To regulate a stable voltage, yes. For this purpose, we are just trying to dump over-voltage to ground and should only need to bias the gate for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is three years old, no proper answer was given.

> The LM5060 datasheet specifies a 9.6 microsecond delay from the onset
>   of a over-voltage condition to the MOSFET gate turning off. So my
>   question is, during that 9.6µs it takes for LM5060 to kick in, how can
>   I ensure that nothing on its down-side gets fried?

"*Delay from OVP Pin > OVPTH to GATE low*" does not necessarily mean that during this interval output voltage rises considerably. The output voltage rise depends on charge pump operation, so you can calculated how much charge a feeble 24-uA pump can deliver into mosfet gate during 9.6 us (hint: 0.23 nC). With this quantity of charge injected Gate-Source voltage will rise for a fraction of volt (see mosfet gate charge diagram) so actually your down-side is safe.

Obviously Cdv/dt is another source of gate charge injection, and measures should be taken that injection is also insignificant during discussed interval.